# Android OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener fires in Portrait only

Tags: android, navigationbar

I'm trying to hide navigation bar in my full-screen Android app as [this document](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation.html) describes. This works, but only in portrait orientation(*). If the app rotates to landscape, the `OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` stops firing. If the app then rotates back to portrait, `OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` starts firing again. I tried to call this code from `onCreate()` and from `onResume()`, and the effect is the same.

```
final View decor=getWindow().getDecorView();
decor.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
    public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
        android.util.Log.d("d", "onSystemUiVisibilityChange");
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                decor.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
            }
        }, 1500);
    }
});
decor.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

(*) It works in whatever orientation the app starts in--if the app starts in landscape, the listener fires only in landscape, if the app starts in portrait, the listener only fires in landscape.

Comment: This is on a physical phone running 4.4.4; on emulator running 4.0, the code above works as I expect.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set it again after the orientation change.
Use android:configChanges="orientation" in the Manifest file under the activity.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    final View decor=getWindow().getDecorView();
    decor.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener (new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
            android.util.Log.d("d", "onSystemUiVisibilityChange");
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    decor.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
                }
            }, 1500);
        }
    });
    decor.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);

    // and here comes the other initializations you have done in the onCreate method.
}
```